# 0=' ' Zero = Space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a file with a numeric field, AgentID.  I made dummy records.  The rows with an AgentID of '0' show up on query

```
select * from ClaimHistory
where AgentID=' '
```

I have verified the field is numeric and has a value of zero with ISNUMERIC & ASCII(AgentID)=0

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is a terrible function, use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`.

Comment: As for the question, a zero length string, or string made up of whitepace will be converted to `0` when compared to an `int`, and so `0 = 0 =TRUE`.

Comment: Why would you ever ask for rows where an integer column equals a space?

Comment: @AaronBertrand You could also ask why would the database engine ever allow you to make that comparison and just silently do *something*.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I think those are pretty long-standing conversion rules that have been there before Microsoft was involved. They could fix it, but oh the things they'd break...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Just checking to validate data and do quality assurance.  It's a new system.   Making sure everything is working right.

Comment: You can validate your data is a numerical value by making it a numerical data type, @givonz . Then it **can't** be a non-numerical value. If you need to then ensure that certain numerical values aren't allowed use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: @Larnu it is declared as int

Comment: Then we go to the comment @AaronBertrand made, givonz: *"Why would you ever ask for rows where an integer column equals a space?"* You have invalidated your prior reason.

Comment: Right. The way SQL Server works, which you can't change, is that if you try to cast a space as an `int`, SQL Server thinks you meant `0`. So, you can deal with that by simply _not doing it_.

Comment: @Larnu I wasn't running the check.  A colleague was.  He did it because the count() for a certain agent doesn't match a physical count in the records and he is trying to reconcile the discrepancy.

Comment: Ok, replace "you" with "someone"... The point remains. If the data type of the column is an `int`, why are you (someone) checking if the value is equal for 0 or more whitespace characters..?

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing an implicit conversion from string to integer.
An explicit conversion shows that space is being converted to zero.

```
select cast(' ' as int) as result
```

---

```
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=db98cb5c7d83b003fc54ec05692f76b6)